# Configure permissions links result in HTTP 500 error

Tags: search, drupal-6, user-permissions

My company's Drupal installation leaves me unable to configure permissions from the admin panel. The key problem arises from the "Administer > By Module" page, where clicking on any of the "configure permissions" links results in a Page Not Found / HTTP 500 Error. A number of the settings pages are broken also, meaning that I cannot change the search_config module's settings, either.

I've checked Drupal's dblog messages, and there's no mention of the HTTP 500 errors there. I also wandered into the host's root (I'm on a shared hosting service) and checked out apache's error logs. No dice. Many errors from the other sites on the server, but only 2 old notifications of RSA certificate issues on my domain.

I've been working at this for about a week now, and I'm deeply perplexed as to what can cause this. I've tried turning off clean URLs, and manually entering what I believe to be the URLs for the settings pages, with the same result. This is developing into quite an issue for me, with permissions configuration offline, and also the search_config settings unavailable. Search_config is a big deal also, as I need to exclude some development nodes from the search index, as they are crashing cron's search indexing, preventing it from being up-to-date. Any light that the brilliant minds here can cast on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I'd also like to add that I'd looked into PHP settings, and that the php timeout is set at 120, with php memory set at 96M. (Just to be complete! ;)  )

Currently running: Drupal 6.22, MySQL 5.1.61, PHP 5.2.17, on a shared Apache 2.2.22 server.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty. Turns out, in spite of increasing the allocated memory from 64M to 96M, a further increase from 96M to 128M for PHP execution was what did the trick. The menus are all online and functioning correctly. I guess the sheer number of installed modules represents a lot of overhead for the server. Thanks to everybody for looking!